# How to implement all possible shortcut connections in a simple Pytorch model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, classification

I am trying to reproduce a result in the paper
PROBEN1 - A Set of Neural Network Benchmark Problems and Benchmarking Rules 1994, Luttz Prechelt with dataset cancer1

The architecture they describe has "all possible feed-forward connections".

With 2 hidden layers and a standard neural network would this mean adding connections:
Input to H2
Input to Output
H1 to Output   ?
The hidden activation functions are sigmoidal and the output activation function is linear.

And if so, how would I do it?

This is my model:

```
class PROBEN1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features=9, hl1=4, hl2=2, out_features=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden1 = nn.Linear(in_features, hl1)
        self.act1 = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.hidden2 = nn.Linear(hl1, hl2)
        self.act2 = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.output = nn.Linear(hl2, out_features)
        self.double()
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.hidden1(x)
        x = self.act1(x)
        x = self.hidden2(x)
        x = self.act2(x)
        return x
```

I have tried concatenating the input of act2 in the forward function but the dimensions are not correct. This is also what I have read online. However, with x new connections we would have x new weights and this method doesn't add any parameters which I find confusing.